# Generic linux usb permission rule

Tags: java, raspbian, libusb, udev

I am trying to use Java4USB to gather usb devices info on Raspian. My java app runs under its own user, but has no access to usb devices.
I have seen that adding udev rules can do the trick, but...

How can I allow usb access to all usb devices to my app, without changing access rules for other users ?

Comment: This sounds like a question more suitable for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) since it is not directly related to Java or any other programmling language, but to the system configuration.

Comment: Ok, I will search there, thanks :)